# LUA: How to change color of WElements / VElements in function

Tags: javascript, function, lua, lua-table, garrys-mod

[How to change color of WElements / VElements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pdcot.png)

How to change color of WElements / VElements in function.
I would like to add that color change to this function:

```
local myBool = true
local c = "weapons/start.wav"
function SWEP:Reload()
    self:EmitSound(c)
    util.ScreenShake( self:GetPos(), 10, 5, 1, 40 )
    myBool = !myBool
end
```

Please help :(

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? also what function is it that you are trying to change the color in?

Comment: I am trying to change the color in WElements / VElements in 
function of SWEP:Reload(). I am tried everything. I don't know how to change color in function or how disable visable of this effect element.

Comment: can you add your current `SWEP:Reload()` code that isnt working to the question

Comment: My function is working but i don't know how to change color of WElement / VElement in that function. I would be really glad for help. (i add my function to post)